# Django fails to load javascript file but has no trouble server a css file in the same directory

Tags: javascript, html, django

I receive a **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** for the javascript file. The page loads fine but the javascript resource isn't obtained despite being in the same static folder as the css file which django has no trouble collecting.

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static'))
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIR=[STATIC_DIR]
```

**html**

```
{% load static %}
asdfs
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/styles.css' %}">
<body id='app'>
    <p>i'm testing again</p>
      <li><a href="www.google.com">google</a></li>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'polls/reactfile.js'
%}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is rendered HTML looks like?

Comment: It renders the paragraph and list and applies the correct css styles to them. it just refuses to load the javascript file.

Comment: Can you provide with the `dir`/`ls` of the relevant content of "polls"?